# Date are changed to 0000-00-00 00:00:00 when applying CSV dump

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv, mysql-connector

I am taking SQL data into csv dump using command

```
"mysql -u test -p test --batch -e "select * from test" | sed 's/\t/","/g;s/^/"/;s/$/"/;s/\n//g' > test.csv"
```

When I am applying this dump back using

```
mysqlimport -u test --ignore-lines=1 --fields-terminated-by=, --fields-escaped-by=\  --fields-optionally-enclosed-by=\" --local -p test ./test.csv
```

The dates column are changed from *2021-06-28 12:08:05* to *0000-00-00 00:00:00* whereas in CSV dates are right. How can I fix it